# use variables in dict python 3

Tags: python, variables, dictionary

I want, use variables in dict, how can I?
ex:

```
field_one= input("Please Enter Field Name? ==> ")
field_two= input("Please Enter Field Name? ==> ")

fields_data = dict(field_one=data_one, field_two=data_two)

print (fields_data)
```

my problem is, the output not show user input, just show:

```
'field_one' = 'data_one'
'field_two' = 'data_two'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dict literal:

```
fields_data = {field_one: data_one, field_two: data_two}
```